# Do I need https url if I want to use facebook javascript or php sdk as user authentication system on my site

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

With Facebook requiring a secure URL for Canvas applications on October 1st,

I am using facebook graph api for facebook users to login, I also have a pagetab and iframe app for my site.

So, My understanding is My page Tab and Iframe app will be blocked from october 1. Will facebook users still be able to login into my site using facebook sdk.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: @pekka I dont have a HTTPS URL.

Comment: Do I need https url if I want to use facebook javascript or php sdk as authentication system on my site.

Comment: yeah, I understand. I don't know the answer, but maybe change your title a bit? Your last comment makes the issue crystal-clear, maybe use a shortened version of it as the title

Answer (score 0):

Check you [application settings](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/) under **Settings**->**Basic** "*App on Facebook*".

There is option "**Secure Canvas URL**".

This is the url that you application is redirected when users are using HTTPS.

You can change it to your HTTPS application.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: I didn't see the comments below. The answer is YES you have to have HTTPS URL by 1 October. Here is official facebook comment: "Acquiring an SSL Certificate. Contrary to some feedback we’ve heard, acquiring an SSL certificate is relatively inexpensive, and the ongoing cost of supporting SSL for most apps is low. The sooner your app supports HTTPS the more secure our platform will become. All Apps on Facebook (Canvas and Page Tabs) must support HTTPS by October 1."  http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/ https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/499/